# Call a function/resolver on each time after move to new page using react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-v5

I am using React navigation in my expo and want to write a resolver that call a function each time to check data , if values are null load it from localStorage/Server, each time when we move to any other page.
How I can achieve that ? is there any Navigation Event that can help me to set a global function?
I tried to read docs here, but did not find a good solution 
https://reactnavigation.org/

I want something like this in my expo/react application.
https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [navigation events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/) to achieve what you want. I suggest you to create a `screen` component and use `navigation.addListener` method in the constructor to subscribe to the events.
If you ask me I would say that one good way is to create a Screen component which you can use as endpoint for navigation in the application.

When you render a component using one of the navigators of the react navigation, the navigation object is passed to the component through the props. So in the constructor of the Screen you are able to access to the navigation.addListener. Use this method to subscribe to `focus` and `blur` events:

```
class ScreenComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.isFocused = true
        this.props.navigation.addListener('didBlur', () => { this.isFocused = false })
        this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => { this.isFocused = true })
    }
}
```

In the body of the event handlers you can implement the data fetching and validations as you wish.

Comment: I did not get the solution, I will add this Listener code on each screen , where i want to fetch some results?

Comment: Whenever you enter into a screen didFocus get called. So if you fetch the data in the body of the method you will have the results as soon as you entered to the screen.